# Display name instead of id

Tags: django, django-forms

I created a form with a choice field call `membersid` which will display the name in the option.

My question is:

How to display the `name` of the object but the `value` shows the `id` of the object?

**forms.py**

```
membersid = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Member.objects.values_list('id',flat=True),required=True)
```

I've tried this but I get the value and the display name are id.

I've inspected the code, the options list is like:

```
<select name="membersid" class="select form-control" required="" id="id_membersid"> 
    <option value="" selected="">---------</option> 
    <option value="15">15</option> 
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option> 
    <option value="21">21</option> 
    <option value="82">82</option>
</select>
```

My expected options list:

```
<select name="membersid" class="select form-control" required="" id="id_membersid"> 
        <option value="" selected="">---------</option> 
        <option value="15">ABC</option> 
        <option value="16">DEF</option>
        <option value="17">GHI</option> 
        <option value="21">JKL</option> 
        <option value="82">MNO</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: `....values_list('id'` use "name" instead of id

Comment: if i use name, the `value` also become `name`

Comment: use "name","id" you get a list back with names and ids

Comment: I want the options list looks like `<option value="15">ABC</option>`

Comment: @Evon Have You __str__ method in your model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forms.py`:

```
membersid = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Member.objects.all(), required=True)
```

in your `models.py`:

```
class Member(models.Model):
   ...
   def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

My setup: Django 2.2

You can simply use *__field_name* show other fields instead of id.
**Example:**

```
users_by_type = User.objects.values_list('user_type__position').annotate(num_user=Count('user_type')).order_by('num_user')
```