# How to show username in django admin form for the connected model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models one is user model and another one is cars model.

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
username = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="User Name")
```

```
class Cars(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cars')
```

Now on `/admin/app/cars/1/change/` page i want to see the username as a normal text in that form below the dropdown of users.

I tried with inline stack but that didn't worked, and throwing error, `User` has to foreign key to `Cars`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display name instead of id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53776894/display-name-instead-of-id)

Answer (score 1):

The text shown in the admin panel is determined by the `__str__` function, so adding something like

```py
def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

to your user model should be enough

Comment: op wants in car model i think this gives wrong

Comment: As far as I understand, OP wants to make it so the "User" dropdown on the Car model change page shows the Username instead of the ID, which is what it shows by default. This is exactly what this answer would achieve.